# What is the most efficient way to execute a lambda inline?

Tags: c#, optimization, code-generation

I have written a parser-generator that has expressions like this:

```
a = f:"foo" "bar" { /* your code here */ }
```

Which, after a fashion, generates code that looks about like this:

```
r0 = this.ReturnHelper<string>(cursor, cursor, () => /* your code here */);
```

This is perfect, because the users can specify an expression, like `f` to just return a value, or they can add an extra set of curly braces and write a method.  So far so good.

Now, I also allow assertions like this:

```
a = w:word !{ w == "disallowed" }
```

Which compiles into something like this, currently:

```
var w = this.ParseWord(...).Value;

...

if (!( w == "disallowed" ))
{
    r2 = new ParseResult<string>(cursor, cursor, string.Empty);
}
```

I would LIKE to have the assertions support the same method-body option that the ReturnHelper provides, but it seems inefficient to have a method `bool AssertionHelper(Func<bool> assertion)` that just calls the predicate.

I was imagining that `new Func<bool>(() => /* your code here */)()` would work, but I'm not sure that it is the most efficient.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

<s>How about `((Func<bool>)(() => /* code */))()`?  Does that avoid an allocation?</s>  Nope, that generates identical IL to the above version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you need to mention `Func<bool>` explicitly at all. Why not just:

```
this.AssertionHelper<string>(cursor, cursor, () => !( w == "disallowed" ))
```

? Assuming it's going to be a single expression with no parameters and it's of type `bool`, that should be fine.

If it needs a parameter `w`, just change it to:

```
this.AssertionHelper<string>(cursor, cursor, w => !( w == "disallowed" ))
```

I believe the MS implementation of the C# compiler will avoid creating a new delegate instance on each invocation of this - but really, does it matter? Have you profiled your application to check whether this is actually a significant performance hit at all? If you have, that's fine - and I've certainly seen some interesting data around *some* cases where micro-optimization for delegates can make a difference - but I wouldn't worry about it until I'd found it's an actual problem.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the call to `AssertionHelper`

Comment: That is, I'm trying to get something analogous to the JavaScript: `function () { /* code */ }()`.

Comment: It's *really* unclear what you want then, to be honest. You said you wanted it to look like `ReturnHelper`, and that passes a delegate... so do you want a delegate or not? It looks like you've already got a version which *doesn't* use a delegate...

Comment: Sorry, what I really want is something to fill in the blanks here:  `if ( ______ )` that will accept a method body.  If I have to wrap it in a call to an as-of-yet-unimplemented method that simply takes a lambda and calls it (that is, what I refered to as `AssertionHelper` above) I will do that, but I was thinking that inline could be faster.

Comment: As far as performance goes, I'm not worried about it for MY parsers, but other people could be pickier than I.  For that reason, I would like to make the most performant choice.  Eliminating a function call is tiny, but still worth it, if I can manage.

Comment: @JohnGietzen: It's often not worth it if it makes the code more complicated - that may end up making it harder to change in a much *more* performance-enhancing way later on. Anyway, no, there's nothing you can do to make an `if` statement take a method body. It has to just be a condition. You could always create a new method and *call* that within the `if` statement though: `if (GeneratedMethod(...))`. Doing that directly *may* be faster than going via a delegate, and for small methods the JIT may well inline it anyway.